# Ext.NET using FormPanelFor multiple times raises error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ext.net, formpanel

I've 2 FormPanelFor definitions:

```
.Items
(
x.FormPanelFor(m => m.SelectedSection).ID("selectedSection"),
x.FormPanelFor(m => m.SelectedGroup).ID("selectedGroup")
)
```

And have model definitions:

```
public class Model_Section
{
    [Field(FieldLabel = "Section Name", AllowBlank = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

     .....
 }

public class Model_Group
{
    [Field(FieldLabel = "Group Name", AllowBlank = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

     .....
 }
```

they both have "Name" property in common and as a result i got this error:

*A Control with an ID of "App.Name" has already been initialized. Please ensure that all Controls have a unique id.
The following Control has the same ID as at least one other Control on the Page. All Controls must have a unique ID.
Control Details
ID: Name.
ClientID: App.Name
Type: TextField
Parent Control Details
ID: selectedGroup
ClientID: App.selectedGroup
Type: FormPanel*

how can i fix this?

Comment: I'm investigating this issue. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: I see you also posted the question in the Ext.NET forums. We'll probably answer there, see http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?23848-Using-multiple-FormPanelFor-raises-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround for this issue would be providing the prefix for form fields manually:

```
.Items
(
x.FormPanelFor(m => m.SelectedSection, htmlFieldName: "SelectedSection").ID("selectedSection"),
x.FormPanelFor(m => m.SelectedGroup, htmlFieldName: "SelectedGroup").ID("selectedGroup")
)
```